# Is there a way to set a block out window in journey builder for emails?

Tags: email, journeybuilder, send-email, timezone

I am trying use use Einstein STO but I am concerned that my users will get the email too early in the morning. I know I can probably just set the STO window to 12 hours or something, but is there another way to set a black out window so users won't get emails (in their own time zone) at let's say 11pm to 5am?

Thanks!